# Can you edit the source code of a google form?

Tags: export, google-forms

I created a large google form without the script editor.  Now I need to duplicate 50 questions, but that is not really possible to do manually.  I'd like to edit my form using the script editor.

I tried opening the live form and copying the source code of the form that way, but it's not in the right format to put back into the script editor.

Is it possible to import an existing form into the script editor?  Or export the source code of a form at all?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution - an add-on called Formfuse.

It can:

- Create questions from a spreadsheet
- Duplicate entire pages of a google form, and put the copies in after whichever page you choose
- Convert your form into code

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like what you are trying to do goes beyond what Google Forms can do, but looking at the add-ons it appears you can do some importing from the google Sheets program so perhaps you can write out the questions in google sheet and import it.